# Dojo 1.9.1 debugging in Firebug

Tags: javascript, dojo, firebug, spring-webflow

I'm using Dojo 1.9.1, which comes as part of Spring Web Flow. I'm trying to debug my JavaScript file with firebug but not able to see my JavaScript files in Firebug's *Script* panel(The file is loading, that I can see in firebug net panel).

dojo.js and other library scripts are visible in firebug, only my script is not visible. I tried to see them with the Chrome DevTools and firefox developer tools, but that didn't help.

There is a Dojo Firebug Extension, but it's not available for the latest Dojo versions.

I'm loading the script using 'require' from my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require( [ "dojo/parser",
               "js/myScript",
               "dojo/domReady!" ], function( parser, myScript ) {
                  myScript.loadElements();
           });
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "Chrome didn't help"? Don't you see those scripts there, neither?

Comment: try the isDebug:true flag in dojoConfig, might be the dojo you are using is packaged up?

Comment: If the scripts are not loading, you normally get a syntax error message inside the console. Have you checked there?

Comment: isDebug:true and the file is loading. There are no errors. The only problem is I'm not able to debug it with firebug because it's not 'showing' under script tab.

Comment: Possibly the files you're using have source map references but the referenced files aren't present.

Comment: A screenshot might help...

Answer (score 0):

make `async:true` in dojoConfig. It was false in my case.

```
dojoConfig= {
        has: {
            "dojo-firebug": true
        },
        isDebug: false,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        async: true
    };
```